How to work out the expected rate of success when there is a guaranteed success on the nth attempt?
I'm looking to work out how to find the expected success rate when given the rate of success but, also after n-1 failed attempts, there the success rate is 100% for the nth attempt.
Intuitively I understand this would make the expected success rate to be higher than what is given for each individual attempt because the distribution is locked to not exceed n attempts.
Example
Fixed success rate = 1%
After 99 consecutive failures, the next attempt has 100% success.
Additionally, is there any way this could be presented visually with a graph i excel or some website that could generate one?

Are attempts independent or not? What is the specific mechanism for assuring success at the nth attempt?

Independent. Not sure what the mechanism would be specifically but you are guaranteed to succeed. So the rate per attempt would be Attempt 1 = 1%, 2 = 1%, ... , n-1 = 1%, n = 100%

Okay, but I'm still guessing here.  Are you trying to tell us you have data concerning how many attempts were needed for a success; that there is a constant independent success rate at each attempt; and that you want to estimate that rate based on your data?  If so, this would be a censored geometric distribution, which tells you what you need to know to apply any likelihood based method.  But if not, which of my guesses are wrong?

If you already know the success rate, as it appears from the phrase "given the rate of success," what are you actually trying to figure out?   The overall success rate would obviously be $( 99\cdot 0.01 + 1\cdot 1) / 100$ with your example.

@whuber I want to know what would the average success rate be.  Maybe think of it like a slot machine. Every individual spin has a 1% chance of success but you can not fail 100 times in a row. On that 100th spin you are 100% guaranteed to win. The true success rate would have to be higher than 1% since you can never go on a losing streak over 100 spins.

@jbowman I know the success rate for each attempt, and the maximum number of consecutive fails possible. So say you took 1 million attempts, how many successes would you expect given teach attempt has 1% chance but you can never fail more than 100 times in a row. Since you cannot fail more than 100 times the actual overall success rate would have to be above 1%.

Such problems are perfect for simulation

You could simulate it as follows:

Perform $n$ Bernoulli trials with probability of success $p$;
If any trials were successful, note the first success;
Otherwise, note the maximum, $n$;
Compute the average rate of success.

set.seed(1234)
MC     <- 1e6
Trials <- numeric(MC)
for(i in 1:MC){
  x <- rbinom(150, 1, 0.007)
  n <- match(1, x)
  Trials[i] <- ifelse(!is.na(n), n, 150)
}
1 / mean(Trials)

# 0.01074207

(Took the example you mentioned in a comment, of $n = 150$, $p=0.007$.)

Easier to read, but much slower, would be to simulate the process literally, one-by-one, but this is so slow I lowered the number of simulations:

While the number of tries is less than $n$, try winning with probability of success $p$;
If any trials are successful, stop and note the number of tries;
Otherwise, note the maximum, $n$;
Compute the average rate of success.

set.seed(1234)
MC     <- 100000
Trials <- numeric(MC)
for(i in 1:MC){
  n <- 0
  while(n < 150){
    n <- n + 1
    if(rbinom(1, size = 1, prob = 0.007) == 1){break}
  }
  Trials[i] <- n
}
1 / mean(Trials)

# 0.01076558


Note that your results conflict with @whuber's above; he has $p=0.01, N=100$ and gets a final probability of approximately $0.0158$, but, given a larger $p$ and smaller $N$, it should be a bigger probability than what you get.  The reason for this is that the answer is 1/mean(Trials), not mean(1/Trials).  Switching the final calculation gives a result of $0.0108$.

@jbowman Nice find, thank you! I've edited the solution

A simple question, stated in an elementary fashion, deserves a short elementary solution.  It also deserves some consideration of what it is actually asking for.  This post offers both.
To establish notation, let $p$ be the success probability, let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{n-1}$ be a sequence of iid random Bernoulli$(p)$ variables; set $X_n=1;$ and let $T$ be the random variable defined by $T = i$ when $X_1=X_2=\cdots=X_{i-1}=0$ and $X_i=1.$
What does the question ask?  Intuitively, since the success rate of one iteration is $1/T,$ it sounds like it's looking to compute $E[1/T]$ (which, by Jensen's Inequality, is not equal to $1/E[T]$).  However, when this experiment is repeated (independently) many times--say $N$ iterations with outcomes $T_1,T_2,\ldots, T_N$--the success rate would be the ratio of successes (one per iteration, obviously) to attempts, $\sum_{j=1}^N T_j.$  The "average success rate" per attempt therefore is
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{N}{\sum_{j}^N T_j} = \frac{1}{\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_j^N T_j} = \frac{1}{E[T]}$$
(by the Weak Law of Large Numbers, which applies because obviously $E[T]\le n\lt \infty.$)
Solution
Because the attempts are independent, their probabilities multiply, giving
$$\Pr(T=i) = \Pr(X_1=0)\Pr(X_2=0)\cdots\Pr(X_{i-1}=0)\Pr(X_i=1) = (1-p)^{i-1}p$$
provided $1\le i \lt n.$  When $i=n,$ the final factor of $p$ is replaced by $1 = \Pr(X_n=1).$
Therefore
$$\begin{aligned}
E[T] &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \Pr(T=i)i\ +\ \Pr(T=n)n\\
&= p\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(1-p)^{i-1}i\ +\ (1-p)^{n-1}n\\
&= \frac{1 - (1-p)^n}{p}.
\end{aligned}$$
(This simplification is straightforward using $\sum_{i=1}^\infty i(1-p)^{i-1}=1/p^2,$ which follows from applying the Binomial Theorem to expand $(1-(1-p))^{-2}$ as a power series in $1-p.$)
Consequently, the answer is

$$1/E[T] = \frac{p}{1 - (1-p)^n}.$$


For those who like to check their work with simulation (I do), here is efficient R code.  Its output (using almost $10^6$ iterations taking one second) for estimating $E[T]$ is
   Mean      SE  Z.Mean 
63.4050  0.0358  0.2230 

The small Z-score indicates the simulated results agree with the formula for $E[T].$
#
# Given a long sequence `x` of attempt outcomes (1 = success), compute
# the average numbers of attempts per success and their standard error.
#
sim <- function(x, n) {
  i <- which(x == 1)
  gaps <- pmin(n, diff(c(0, i)))
  N = length(gaps)
  c(Mean = mean(gaps), SE = sqrt(var(gaps) / N), N = N)
}
#
# Specify the problem.
#
p <- 1/100
n <- 100
n.iter <- 1e6  # Approximate number of iterations
theoretical <- (1 - (1-p)^n) / p
N <- ceiling(n.iter / p)
#
# Perform the simulation.
#
set.seed(17)
system.time(
  observed <- sim(sample(0:1, N, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-p, p)), n)
)
#
# Display the results in comparison to the theoretical value (as a Z-score).
#
SE <- observed["SE"]
Z = (observed["Mean"] - theoretical) / SE
d <- 1 + ceiling(-log10(SE))
(c(round(observed["Mean"], d), signif(SE, 3), Z = signif(Z, 3)))


Ah, I missed that Binomial expansion! (+1)

@jbowman An alternative is to recognize it as the negative derivative of the geometric power series $1 + (1-p) + (1-p)^2+\cdots = 1/p,$ immediately giving the answer.  But that requires a little more sophistication than the Binomial Theorem ;-).

I wonder whether this could be modelled via Hypergeometric distribution. Lets say you have $M=\left(N-1\right)+A$ boxes. And out of them $A$ boxes have a prize. So choosing the boxes randomly you will never go without finding the prize for more than $N-1$ times.
Probability of finding the prize in one try is:
$$
p\left(k=1\, |\,n=1\right)=\frac{\left(\begin{array}\\A \\1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}\\N-1 \\0\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}\\N-1+A \\1\end{array}\right)}=\frac{A}{N-1+A}
$$
Where $n=1$ is your number of tries and $k$ is your number of prizes. As you see, one can make this probability high or low by choosing how large $A$ is compared to $N$.
If for each of your attempts you have more than one try then probability of finding a prize in one attempt would be something like:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}p\left(k\,| n\right)
$$

A different problem is: Probability of success for $N-1$ tries is $\pi$, on $N$-th try there is a guaranteed success. Process resets after every success. What is the ratio of success/attempts when number of attempts $\gg N$?
Here we may simply ask how many attempts, on average does one need before having a success. $f=0,1,\dots N$ be the number of attempts before one hits success.
By definition of the problem:
$$
\begin{align}
P\left[f=N\right]=0
\end{align}
$$
Let there be $N-1$ boxes. Let the number of boxes with prizes be $K\sim Binomial\left(N-1,\pi\right)$ where $\pi$ is the probability of success. Then the probability of choosing $f$ random boxes and finding no success is:
$$
P[0 \le f|K < N-1] = \alpha\cdot \frac{\left(\begin{array}\\K \\0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}\\N-1-K \\f-0\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}\\N-1 \\f\end{array}\right)}=\alpha\cdot\frac{\left(\begin{array}\\N-1-K \\f\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}\\N-1 \\f\end{array}\right)}
$$
Where $\alpha$ is such that above probability is normalized, i.e. $\sum_{f=0\dots N-1}P[0 \le f|K < N-1]=1 $
With this you can compute the expectation value for $f$ given $K$.
$$
E\left[f|K\right]=\sum_{f=0\dots N}P[f|K]\cdot f
$$
Finally, you can use the distribution for $K$ to get unconditional expectation value:
$$
E\left[f\right]=E\left[E\left[f|K\right]\right]
$$
The then number of your successes after $J\gg N$ attempts should be $J/\left(E\left[f\right]+1\right)$. Not sure one can find a closed-form expression for this, but it is certainly computable in a deterministic way, without needing to simulate.

Would this not result in a change in chance to succeed at every attempt? The question I'm asking is that it stays the same at every attempt except for 1 after 99 consecutive fails which is guaranteed then it goes back to the original chance and you go again. Like a roulette wheel but every time you go 99 spins without winning the 100th spin is rigged in your favour.

@BLey99 If the mechanism is such that you get one success rate for $N-1$ attempts and then it switches, then there is nothing to calculate. If I get $N-1$ attempts, and they are all independent, then this is simply series of Bernoulli trials. If I get $N+$ attempts, success rate is 1.

Surely there would be some way to calculate it or are you saying the only way to get a result would be through a simulation? It seems like far too simple of a problem to have no way to calculate it

@BLey99 . Perhaps, I am not understanding you. What you seem to be saying to me is 'the rate of success is $p$ for number of tries below $N-1$, $1$ for more tries than that'. Then you ask what is the rate of success. Well, it is what you told me in the previous sentence. You fixed it in definition.

It's not that one cannot calculate it, it's with such definition there is nothing to calculate

The rate of success for each individual attempt is 1%. But on the 100th attempt it is guaranteed to succeed. So worst case scenario it takes you 100 tries, but sometimes it will take less so the overall success rate would have to be above 1%.

SO if you had 100000 tries, how many times would you expect to succeed given you cannot possible fail 100x in a row

@BLey99, So you get a guaranteed success after $N-1$ fails, and then it resets. What happens if you get success on $N/2$ attempt. Will it reset then, so your next guaranteed success is at $N-1+N/2$ or will I get a guaranteed success on $N-1$ as before?

After every success your fail counter would reset

@BLey99, see addendum

In your hypergeometric model, the successes are not independent, contradicting the OP's assumption.
